# VB How to Clear existing items in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to search the information from the sql server then show at the listview. Everytime I click search it won't clear the existing records based on the past time searching. I've tried item.clear, it will only show me the new search but it won't clear all the existing records. Can someone help please?

```
   Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim strNameSource As String
    Dim strPhoneSource As String
    Dim strBothSource As String

    If OpenConnect() = True Then
        Try
            If ChkCustName.Checked = True Then

                strNameSource = "SELECT TCI.strLastName + ', ' + TCI.strFirstName AS strName,TCI.strPhoneNumber,CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckIn, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckOut,101),TRT.strRoomType,TR.strRoom FROM TCheckInInfo AS TCI,TRoom AS TR,TRoomType AS TRT WHERE TCI.intRoomID = TR.intRoomID AND TR.intRoomTypeID = TRT.intRoomTypeID AND intCheckInStatusID = 1 AND TCI.strLastName ='" & txtLastName.Text & "'"
                SearchReservation(strNameSource)
            ElseIf ChkPhoneNumber.Checked = True Then
                strPhoneSource = "SELECT TCI.strLastName + ', ' + TCI.strFirstName AS strName,TCI.strPhoneNumber,CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckIn, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckOut,101),TRT.strRoomType,TR.strRoom FROM TCheckInInfo AS TCI,TRoom AS TR,TRoomType AS TRT WHERE TCI.intRoomID = TR.intRoomID AND TR.intRoomTypeID = TRT.intRoomTypeID AND intCheckInStatusID = 1 AND TCI.strPhoneNumber ='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "'"
                SearchReservation(strPhoneSource)
            ElseIf ChkCustName.Checked = True And ChkPhoneNumber.Checked = True Then
                strBothSource = "SELECT TCI.strLastName + ', ' + TCI.strFirstName AS strName,TCI.strPhoneNumber,CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckIn, 101),CONVERT(VARCHAR,TCI.dtmCheckOut,101),TRT.strRoomType,TR.strRoom FROM TCheckInInfo AS TCI,TRoom AS TR,TRoomType AS TRT WHERE TCI.intRoomID = TR.intRoomID AND TR.intRoomTypeID = TRT.intRoomTypeID AND intCheckInStatusID = 1 AND TCI.strPhoneNumber ='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "' AND TCI.strLastName ='" & txtLastName.Text & "'"
                SearchReservation(strBothSource)
            End If
            txtLastName.Clear()
            txtPhoneNumber.Clear()
        Catch excError As Exception
            WriteLog(excError)
            'End program
            Application.Exit()
        End Try
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub SearchReservation(ByVal strSource As String)
    Dim itemcollection(100) As String
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim ListViewItem As New ListViewItem

    lstReservation.Items.Clear()

    Try

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSource, cnn)
        Adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Adapter.Fill(Ds, "Table")

        'Now adding the Items in Listview

        If Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            ' Something went wrong. warn user
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Could not find the Customer", "Customer finding Error", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            lstReservation.BeginUpdate()

            For Row = 0 To Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                For Column = 0 To Ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

                    itemcollection(Column) = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(Row)(Column).ToString()
                Next
                ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(itemcollection)
                lstReservation.Items.Add(ListViewItem)
            Next
            lstReservation.EndUpdate()

        End If
    Catch excError As Exception
        WriteLog(excError)
        'End program
        Application.Exit()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no code there to clear the existing items.  And never ever concat values into strings to create a query - use SQL parameters.  I would also note that most of that code would not be needed using a DataGridView

Comment: the clear the existing item that's what I have problem with. I tried remove,removeat, but I still don't know how to clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues with your code, but I'll focus on your immediate issue.

You keep filling the DataSet with *new* tables, but you keep using the original table that is still in position zero of the DataSet.

I would venture a guess that you need to clear the rows of your DataTable:

```
If Ds.Tables.Contains("Table") Then
  Ds.Tables("Table").Rows.Clear()
End If
lstReservation.Items.Clear()
```

of just clear any tables there:

```
Ds.Tables.Clear()
lstReservation.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was focusing on clear the items at listview, even didn't think about the tables! I appricate that.